# Unable to bind in asp.net grid Template Column

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am having trouble accessing the data field. I receive the error: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

I can get the value but using <%# getOpenJobs((string)Eval("ParentPart")) %> but I need to use it in the if to display a certian picture if it passes the condition. Is there a better way to do this or am i just missing something simple?

```
               <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="hasOpenJobs" HeaderText="">
                <ItemTemplate>
                        <% if (getOpenJobs((string)Eval("ParentPart")) > 1)
                           { %>
                            <img src="../images/job-icon.gif" alt="Open Jobs" />
                         <%} %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these cases, I usually create a method in the code-behind to send back the final generated HTML. E.g.

```
<ItemTemplate>
<%# GetJobImageHtml((string)Eval("ParentPart")) %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Then do whatever logic you need in the `GetJobImageHtml()` method and return a HTML string.